# Is it correct and natural to say "work in a managerial role"?

Tags: collocations

Is it correct and natural to say *work in a managerial role*? For example:

> The job description says that to be considered for the position you need to have at least one year **working in a managerial role**.

If it sounds off, could you tell me how you would phrase it?

Comment: The more likely usage is: **.....you need to have at least one year of experience in a managerial role.**(Or possibly...**at least one year of managerial experience.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it correct and natural to say “work in a managerial role”?

Not quite. "Managerial role" is fine, and so are "managerial position" and "managerial level". But the phrasing of the example sentence is incorrect.

> The job description says that to be considered for the position you need to **have** at least one year **working** in a managerial role.

Note how you have "have at least" in the example sentence, which here implies "a full year spent in a managerial role" — a completed year. And so, you can't use the continuous "working" here in that fashion.

Perhaps the simplest way to rephrase this is how Ronald Sole suggests in the comments:

> ... to be considered for the position, you need to **have** at least one year of [work] experience in a managerial role/position.

or

> ... to be considered for the position, you need to **have** worked in a managerial position for at least one year.

If you want to use "working", you would say something like

> ... you need to have spent at least one year working at a managerial level

> Minimum of 5 years of experience with a proven track record working at a managerial level ... (*from google*)